# Returning the appended row number after sheet.appendRow

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way of returning the newly appended row number into a Google sheet with the following `appendRow` code? I can guarantee that the sheet will not be sorted but I cannot guarantee that the sheet will not have another row append before I call the number of rows of data in the sheet.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Appends a new row with 3 columns to the bottom of the
// spreadsheet containing the values in the array
sheet.appendRow(["a man", "a plan", "panama"]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`appendRow()` returns the `Sheet` object for chaining. If you want the row number, you need to call `getLastRow()` ([see docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)) immediately after appending. If you have concurrent appends, you can use the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service) to make sure to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I will try the lock service - thanks.